# Logs from external lib (c++) on release version of Android app

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I have external library attached to android app. Lib is developed in c++ and uses log.h library (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/liblog/include/android/log.h) to print logs. Android app in debug config prints logs. Other configuration for testers must have isDebbuguble set to true in gradle to do that. Problem: I don't want to do set `isDebugguble = true` because of security reasons. Is there any other way to print logs from the lib in "testers" config (Separate build type)?

Comment: Same issue here! Anyone - help, please :)